# How to remove Tag Ranges

Tags: mongodb

We can remove Tags using `sh.removeShardTag()`, but how we can remove TagRange?

e.g I have a range, and want to remove.

```
tag: 0_to_F  { "_id" : "0" } -->> { "_id" : "F" }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no remove tag range helper function (see [this page](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6352) for a request to add). For now you will have to modify the **tags** collection in the **config** database manually. I would restart your mongos processes after to make sure they reflect.